# Python join dataframes on index

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

How do I join 2 dataframes on their indexes?

[image]

```
  y_final= y_test2.merge(df, left_on='index', right_on='index')
  KeyError: 'index'
```

Comment: Can you post dataframe examples as text?

Comment: We need dataframe and expected output for our reference?

Comment: There are multiple meanings to "join" - inner, outer, merge, update.... expected output helps narrow that down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one!

```
pd.merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```